# how to display custom message when open a file in a specific directory?

Tags: linux, vim, autocmd

I use the `autocmd VimEnter * echo "some text"` but this is showing for every file when I open.

How to restrict this only for a specific folders? Let's say `/tmp/test/sample.txt`. If I want to use the above logic for `sample.txt` in `/tmp/test`, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were along the correct lines, just change the * to the path that you want to apply the autocmd to:

```
autocmd VimEnter /tmp/test/* echo "Some text for /tmp/test"
```

Comment: what I am expecting is when I vim /tmp/test/sample.txt  should see the custom message but with this I did not see the actual expected message.

Comment: Please provide the exact line that you're using as I get the desired behaviour, a message is printed at the bottom of the vim window. Please also confirm that you're using vim and not a different vi derivative.

Comment: applogies, Yeah it is working fine as I expected. One QQ how to do with vim and vi and View in a single command any chance to figure it out?